# Can't play audio suddenly on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: usb, sound, video, pulseaudio, alsa

I had used Roland QUAD-CAPTURE on Ubuntu 16.04.1 without any problems. But it can't play audio suddenly since some days ago. I tried to fix this problem by un-muting devices, upgrading kernel, changing USB cable, but it still can't play anything.

### Issues

- Can't play audio with Roland QUAD-CAPTURE on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

  - Before, it can play audio without any problems.
  - In another device, NVIDIA HDMI can play audio.
  - It works on Windows. (it may not be physical device issue.)

### some debug informations

- alsa-info.sh: http://pastebin.com/w4CuUXEg

#### aplay -l

```
 # aplay -l
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: QUADCAPTURE [QUAD-CAPTURE], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
   Subdevices: 0/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

#### aplay -vv /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

aplay stuck in following state.

```
 # aplay -vv /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav 
 Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
 ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
 Its setup is:
   stream       : PLAYBACK
   access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
   format       : S16_LE
   subformat    : STD
   channels     : 1
   rate         : 48000
   exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
   msbits       : 16
   buffer_size  : 24000
   period_size  : 6000
   period_time  : 125000
   tstamp_mode  : NONE
   tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
   period_step  : 1
   avail_min    : 6000
   period_event : 0
   start_threshold  : 24000
   stop_threshold   : 24000
   silence_threshold: 0
   silence_size : 0
   boundary     : 6755399441055744000
 ######            +                                | 34%
```

Comment: How is PulseAudio configured?

Comment: @CL. completely default, except volume settings.

Comment: So PA is configured to play to some HDMI output?

Comment: No. In testing, I changed output device to use QUAD-CAPTURE.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to fix this problem.
This problem may be caused by mismatching of sampling rate?

### Requirement

- Environment running Windows or OS X
- QUAD-CAPTURE Driver (To fix, need software control panel)

### How to fix?

1. Open software control panel

   - Windows: Open in control panel
   - OS X: There may be in /Applications/Roland*
2. Reset configuration in "Device" menu
3. Change sample rate to **44.1 kHz**

### Memo

[alsa-capabilities](https://lacocina.nl/detect-alsa-output-capabilities)

```
 4) USB Audio Class Digital alsa audio output interface `hw:1,0'
 - device name       = QUAD-CAPTURE                                                
 - interface name    = USB Audio                                                   
 - usb audio class   = 2 - isochronous asynchronous                                
 - character device  = /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p                                           
 - rates per format  = S32_LE:              44100Hz                                
 - monitor file      = /proc/asound/card1/stream0
```